# vuejs Computed data detecting if model has been updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, immutability

I'm trying to detect if a Model Data has not been changed within a Vue Computed data.

I have two sets of Variables that need to be checked,
before Computed:filteredItems should return a new list or current list.

Below are two data i'm checking

- text ( the text input )
- selectedInput ( currently selected item )

**Current Behavior:**

I've changed, **selectedInput** to null, this updates Computed:filteredList to be triggered. which is expected.

The first Condition is to make sure that this update returns current list if **text === selectedInput.text**, work as expected

However, I need a second condition to detect if **text** has not been changed.

```
<input v-model="text" />
<ul>
   <li v-for="item in filteredItems" @click="text=item.text"></li>
</ul>

{
  data():{
     text: 1,
     items: [],
     tempList: [],
     selectedItem: {text: 1}
  },
  computed: {
     filteredItems(){
        // when selectedItem.text === current text input, do not run
        if (this.selectedItem.text === text) return this.tempList;

        // how do i detect if selectedItem.text has not been changed
        if (this.selectedItem.text.hasNotChange??) return this.tempList;
     }
  }
}
```

Data Flow: 1update the text > 2filter list > 3click on listItem, update (1) text

1. [input(text): update on type ] >
2. [li(filteredItem): filter list on type by value (text) and (selectedInput.text) ] >
3. [li(item)@click: update (1), and also another value(selectedInput.text) input(text) to equal (item.text) ]

This cycle works until I have action somewhere else that updates selectedInput.text

is there something i can do with a setter/getter for the **Text** model.

Comment: may i know why? what are you going to do if it has not been changed ? If it haven't changed, the computed setter won't even be triggered. what you want is probably [watch](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property)

Comment: Save the original value of text and compare text to it.

Comment: @JacobGoh, if the FIRST value is not changed, i'll return the current temporaryList. I hit another problem using Watch. I'm doing some tricky 2-way binding type of thing. which relies on TWO Variables

Comment: @RoyJ, yah im trying out with the setter/getter to see if i can make a temporayCopy of the "text" model for it to be compared. will post the result if it's working

Comment: Have you considered using a watcher instead of a computed?

Comment: @connexo, watchers causes other problems, A I have a different way of updating the "watched variable" and it needs to be handled differently, and watchers made it more like an infinite loop binding for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work using a temp variable

```
data(){
   return: {
      text: "",
      temp: {
         text
      }
   }
}

computed(){
   filteredList(){
       var temporaryList,originalList,filteredList


       if ((this.text === $store.state.selectedText )||
           (this.text === this.temp.text ) ) {
                return temporaryList || originalList
           }

       // update
       this.temp.text = this.text

       return filteredList
   }
}
```

thought it would be a bad practice to update variables within a Computed method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable, `changed`. Watch `selectedItem.text`, and set `changed` to `true`. In a watcher on `text`, set `changed` to `false`.